# Generate Sample XML: Could not find any element declaration for a root element

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to generate sample XML from an XSD. I am using Altova XMLSpy to generate schemas. When I go to "Generate Sample XML File" I receive an error saying

> Could not find any element declaration for a root element.

The program has worked perfectly for all other XSD files I have tried. How can I get this file converted or another program I can use to generate this sample XML?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your XSD, we might guess that it lacks any global element definitions.  It could, for example, be a collection of `xsd:simpleType` and `xsd:complexType` definitions.  If this is the case, you should still be able to create some sample XML if you can provide a root element:

1. Decide the type of the root element of the XML you wish to generate.
2. Create an `xsd:element` declaration of the desired type.
3. Place the created `xsd:element` into the XSD directly, or place it in
   its own file and import or include the type definitions into the new
   XSD.

Providing the sample XSD (or preferably a minimum version of it that still exhibits the issue) would have allowed us to be more specific in answering your question.